# How do I create and save an Object based on the HTML user input

Tags: javascript, html, object

Ok, so I am trying to create a registration form which requires Username, First name, Last name, Password, and Email. These will be filled out by the user. 
I have two separate js files - a controller, where I (will) have the logic for the registration, and an "account holder", where I have an array of objects (users).

In the accounts file, I have a constructor User:

```js
function User(email,username,firstName,lastName, birthdate,password){
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

In the code below I connect the controller to the accounts file and create an eventListener for when the registration button is pressed:

(the variables in the beginning are the input fields in the HTML file)

```js
var regEmail = document.querySelector('.register-email-input');
var regUsername = document.querySelector('.register-username-input');
var regFirstName = document.querySelector('.register-firstName-input');
var regLastName = document.querySelector('.register-lastName-input');
var regBirth = document.querySelector('.register-birth-input');
var regPassword = document.querySelector('.register-password-input');
var confirmPass = document.querySelector('.register-confirmPass-input');
var regBtn = document.querySelector('.button-register-account');

function include(file) {

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = file;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.defer = true;

    document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(script);
}

include('./js/accounts.js');


regBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var user = new User(regEmail.value, regUsername.value, regLastName.value, regBirth.value, regPassword.value);
    
    console.log(user);  //check if the data is correct
   
})
```

So far the code works, but I want to save the newly created Object (user) in the accounts file. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use localstorage to store the information of the user and then retrieve them from the second js file

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of users in the accounts file and then add the newly created user in the array. Also add the method of adding into users array in user function in accounts file.
When you finished creating a new user, just call this add method to be added in the user's list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save on accounts file since it is just a model scheme of users.

One way to save data on browser is to save on localStorage (example below). However, it is not recommended to save user data (like passwords) on browser.

Save the User object

`localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))`

Retrieve User Object

`let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))`

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, if your both js files are included in the same html file, you can share the variables by declaring it as global.

So declare a variable as

`var user;`

then

```
regBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    user = new User(regEmail.value, regUsername.value, regLastName.value, regBirth.value, regPassword.value);

    console.log(user.email);  //check if the data is correct

});
```

This variable will be accessible from both your js files if both files are included in the same html files.

Otherwise you can save in localStorage as a json string and retrieve like the other answers.